# How can I override magento 2 Model Bundle Indexer Price?

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3.3, php-7.2

I'm trying to override magento 2's default bundle indexer price :
Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Indexer\Price

I created a module Abc_Bundlecstm with the following di.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Indexer\Price" type="Abc\Bundlecstm\Model\ResourceModel\Indexer\Price" />
</config>
```

module.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Abc_Bundlecstm" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

And the following Abc/Bundlecstm/Model/ResourceModel/Indexer/Price.php file:

```
<?php

namespace Abc\Bundlecstm\Model\ResourceModel\Indexer;

/**
 * Bundle products Price indexer resource model
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Price extends \Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Indexer\Price
```

I have overwritten the private function "applyFixedBundleSelectionPrice" but even after clearing, activating and registering the module and the cache my model is never used when I run bin/magento indexer:reindex.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why you need to rewrite this model? You might break future upgrades or it make it very painful. Let me know your requirement so that more accurate approach can be suggested.

Comment: Where you created di.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be valid.

Your function `applyFixedBundleSelectionPrice` is never called because of **private** access.

Private access make the function only callable and accessible directly in its class.

In your case, all the class `Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Indexer\Price` is written with private accesses.

**To answer your question, you should rewrite *all* the class content in your class and apply your code inside it.**

Please keep in mind that this solution **is not recommended** :

-> Error in index can make your magento unstable

-> The file will not be updated when updating magento

Hope this helps